Pytest - reordeing the test files
In the existing projects PyTests runs the files in alphabetical order one after other.
The file name are archive_test.py, config_test.py, controller_test.py ...etc.
I want the controller_test.py  to be ran before config_test.py when I execute pytest -s. How to achieve this? Is there any other logical apart from renaming?
I tried adding.  ordering = [" controller_test.py", "config_test.py"]  in conftest.py but doesnt seem to be working
